# NoRM - FindAndModify with arguments

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm

Is it possible to specify fields while doing a FindAndModify, so only one field is returned?

Also, is it possible to do an upsert, to create the object if it doesn't exist.

As per:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

I can't see any way of adding the additional arguments

**EDIT:**
Seems to be some confusion - I am using NoRM (C#)
https://github.com/atheken/NoRM/

Comment: What's wrong with the 'fields' parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible actually in NoRM. You could fork the project and add an overloaded FindAndModify method to the file NoRM/Collections/MongoCollectionGeneric.cs to support this behavior.

I think you might need to add a field `fields` in the anonymous object passed to findOne.

```
var returnValue = cmdColl.FindOne(new
{
  findandmodify = this._collectionName,
  query = query,
  update = update,
  sort = sort,
  fields = fields
}).Value;
```

And maybe a pull request :)

Comment: what should the value of fields be? an expando object? another anonymous type?

Comment: Both are supported by NoRM, as far as I remember. You could just use a generic argument on your method and NoRM will use the type at runtimeg benefitting from the expando or using reflection on your anonymous type.

Comment: Do you have an example..? I found a bug in mongodb that prevented me doing some of what i wanted - http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2626

Comment: Can't you do it the other way, by specifying the fields you want ?

Comment: My doc has only 2 fields- ID, and value.. (I'm doing an auto-increment type operation based on http://shiflett.org/blog/2010/jul/auto-increment-with-mongodb) - so have to explicitly EXCLUDE ID

Comment: NoRM already has a generateID (HiLo algorithm) based method, which does ok- but I want to use the above method, and make it quicker. Can do the whole operation in one command, as in my question (try it in mongo shell- it works!)

Comment: Issue is still not resolved. atheken never replies to tweets... guess the project is dying..?

Answer (score -2):

Use the fields specifier. e.g.

```
db.foo.findAndModify({query:{_id:"myid"},
update:{$set:{priority:78}},new:true,fields:{_id:1,priority:1}})
```

Comment: sorry- you missed the crucial bit - NoRM (the wrapper for C#)